# Heroku run command does not answer on my network

Tags: heroku, network-protocols, server-configuration

Hi I am running some scripts trough the heroku run command CLI but I am having trouble with this on certain networks. What ports are used for this tool? I thought heroku toolbelt used ssh is it so and is it using standard ports? I can't find this information on herokus forums. Does any one know?

The strange part is I get initial contact with heroku but I then get this error after a long wait.

```
Error:       Connection timed out - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

Im not sure if it is a port problem but it seams to only happen on one of my networks which is strictly controlled. So that is why im interested in ports.

Comment: The question is thus what ports are used by the heroku run command?